# Memory Leak of Dictionary used in singleton

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, memory-leaks, singleton

I have singleton. It contains a 2 dictionaries.

```
struct Stat {
    var statHash:String
    var displayDescription:String
    var displayName:String
    var displayIcon:String
    var statIdentifier:String
}

class Singleton {

    static let sharedInstance = Singleton()

    var statsDesc = [String:Stat]()
    var test = [String: String]()

    init() {
        test["a"] = "b"
    }
}

let singlton = Singleton.sharedInstance
```

On using the leaks tool, I am getting a memory leak of the second dictionary(String, String).

[image]

Could someone please explain why this happens?

[Link to the project on dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/djalkmwwu0ct3la/TestJsonLeak.zip?dl=0)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Memory leaks are really difficult to diagnose with just a snippet of code. If you can share your project, someone here can help you get to a solution.

Comment: Actually, that is the whole project.  I noticed this leak in my big project and decided to test just singleton with dictionaries in separate one. [Singleton project Dropbox Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/djalkmwwu0ct3la/TestJsonLeak.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was swift bug [Memory Leak from Multiple Dictionary Properties](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3661)

Answer (score 0):

In effect, a singleton is a leak.  Since the singleton holds a reference to itself, it is never released and neither are any of its properties.

The Leaks tool noted that `singlton` went out of scope, but the memory that was allocated was not released, so it flags a leak.  In this case, however, a leak is exactly what you want.

Comment: The problem is that only second dictionary is flagged as a leak, not singleton itself. If i remove dictionaries and write smth like that:
class Singleton {
    
    static let sharedInstance = Singleton()
    
    var num: Int
    
    init() {
        num = 3
    }
}
leak dessapears.